# Getting "Unknown String Error"

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-dateutil

I wrote a function that scrapes data from a website for multiple zip codes.  The code works for most zip codes, but there are some where I'm getting an Unknown String Error.

Here is the code I'm using

```
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd
import random
import os
url = 'https://www.sittercity.com/jobs/search?distance=50&&page=1&per_page=100000&search_strategy=babbysitting_job&&selected_facets%5Bnew_jobs%5D=true&sort=relevance&zipcode=94513'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
posts = [t.text for t in soup.find_all(class_ = "item posted-by")]
dates = [parse(item, fuzzy = True) for item in posts]
```

The error is coming from the 34th item in the posts list.  However the datatype of each element in the list is the same, so I'm confused. Also the 33rd item in the list seems to work.  For example:

This works:

```
dates_single = parse(posts[32], fuzzy = True)
```

But this doesn't (?)

```
dates_single = parse(posts[33], fuzzy = True)
```

Here are the values of posts[32] and posts[33]

```
>>> posts[33]
u'Posted by April A. on 3/28/2016'
>>> posts[32]
u'Posted by Chandrika M. on 3/30/2016'
```

I read through the datetil.parser documentation and none of the "Unknown String Error" use cases seem to fit.

Comment: Can you post the values of `posts[32]` and `posts[33]`?

Comment: Just posted them in my question

Comment: So I will hazard a guess...`dates_single()` is picking up on "April" in posts[33] and trying to convert that to a date!  What happens if you set `fuzzy` to False?

Comment: Also, you can test it by manually changing `posts[33]` to not include the word `April`, to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: haha, wow that's a good thought.  Setting fuzzy to false gives me an unknown error for both.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was a long-shot.

Comment: Even replacing the word april with some abritrary string gives me an error.    I'm really perplexed.

Comment: Is `parse()` a `dateutil.parser.parse()`? If so, it has to be fuzzy matched April as month name.

Comment: Sorry just edited my question.  SHould've included my import statement

Comment: from dateutil.parser import parse

Comment: I tried replacing April though and I still got the same error

Comment: Do you *have* to parse the whole string (e.g. posts[33])? if the structure of that string is consistent and the date part is always the last "word" then you could just split out that last part and parse it alone.

Comment: Hey gariepy, you were right.  When I replaced April I had fuzzy set to false which was the reason it still gave me an error.  Thank you gariepy, Rogalski, and CaptSolo.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error occurs due to conflict between `April` (detected as month name) and `3` detected as month number.

Minimal example:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse(u'Posted by Chandrika M. on 3/30/2016', fuzzy=True)  # datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 30, 0, 0)
parse(u'Posted by April A. on 3/28/2016', fuzzy=True)  # ValueError: Unknown string format
parse(u'Posted by XYZ A. on 3/28/2016')  #  datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 28, 0, 0)
```

Since your format is well-defined you may simply perform straightforward conversion, without any heuristics.

```
s = u'Posted by April A. on 3/28/2016'
datetime.datetime.strptime(s.split()[-1], "%m/%d/%Y")  # datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 28, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: As a clarification, it's not that it fuzzy-matched April as a month name. The `fuzzy` keyword just refers to the fact that the parser will ignore anything in the string that's not a date. The reason this fails is because it finds 2 values for the month. `parse('April 28/2016')` would parse to `datetime(2016, 4, 28)` with or without `fuzzy`.